# What is an example of driver and receiver chips for a PCB?

Tags: pcb-design, driver, receiver

I am watching some tutorials on signal integrity and the instructor keeps referring to a driver and a receiver. I am a little confused what exactly this would be when designing a PCB is the driver like a microcontroller sending the signal? What is the receiver then?

Comment: It kinda depends on the context.  In an analog mixer, I would use an amplifier (like an op amp) as a *driver* to reduce my output impedance, which improves the fidelity of the signal, especially with a reactive (capacitive or inductive) load.  In a digital circuit, a similar "driver" would serve to improve the shape of the digital wave form and therefore reduce the error rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In digital logic, a driver is just a buffer (a gate whose output is the same as its input) designed to produce a relatively high output current, so that it can deliver a signal across a relatively long (and high capacitance) trace. For example, a 74LVC244 chip is often described as a "buffer/driver" chip.

A receiver is a buffer designed to be able to fully switch its output with a relatively low amplitude input signal. You won't find too many chips sold specifically as receivers, but there are several that are called *transceivers*, combining driver and receiver functions.

Generically, your instructor might just be using these terms to mean whatever gate drives a signal onto a line and whatever gate receives the signal from the line.

Comment: so would this be like an ic sending a signal that will control what another ic does?

Comment: @Brit, for whatever reason you want to send a signal from one place to another.

Answer (score 0):

Some other chip that receives the high-speed signal, for example a DAC.

Comment: Examine the CAN transceiver, the MicroChip 2551.